# Google Places JS API: autocomplete search with setInterval on markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have successfully implemented some code for returning results from the *Places Search Box*, but I would like to use **setInterval** so there is some delay in between dropping the markers on the map. I'm having some trouble with my attempt at it. Any help is much appreciated as I'm getting really frustrated with what I thought would be a simple task! :)

**This code works, with no setInterval delay:**

```js
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
        
    var image = {
        url: 'img/marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(48, 48),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(24, 48),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    };

    // Create a marker for each place.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: image,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var request = { reference: place.reference };
    markers.push(marker); //Push to Markers array.
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

}
```

**My attempt at setInterval, that does not work:**

```js
var i = 0;
var place;
place = places[i];
var interval = setInterval(function () {

    var image = {
        url: 'img/marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(48, 48),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(24, 48),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    };

    // Create a marker for each place.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: image,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });
  
    i++;

    var request = { reference: place.reference };
    markers.push(marker); //Push to Markers array.
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

    if (i >= markers.length) clearInterval(interval);

}, 500);
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Can you put together a jsFiddle with a complete example (e.g. one where places[] is defined?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `setInterval` is not the proper method, you must use `setTimeout` (`setInterval` runs the function again and again, while `setTimeout` runs the function once....for each marker)
2. to achieve the desired effect you must increment the delay(e.g. by using `i*500`)

Example:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.520006, 13.404953),
      zoom: 22
    }),
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map),
    markers = [],
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(map.getCenter());




  service.radarSearch({
    types: ['restaurant'],
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 5000
  }, function(places, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var image = {
        url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/dd-via.png'
      };
      for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

        setTimeout((function(place) {
          return function() {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              icon: image,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            markers.push(marker);
          }
        })(place), 250 * i)

      }

    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```